# ui grid filter toggling not working, "type was not recognised"?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have a filter toggling button for toggle  $scope.uiGridOptions.enableFiltering .

```
$scope.toggleFiltering= function () {
        $scope.uiGridOptions.enableFiltering = !$scope.uiGridOptions.enableFiltering;
        $scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange( uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN );
    }
```

{{uiGridOptions.enableFiltering}} changes true and false, but filter in my grid doesn't hide/show.

```
  $scope.uiGridOptions = {
        enableFiltering:true,//default
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        },
        columnDefs: [                
             {
                 field: 'name'
                 , name: 'Name'

             }]
  }
```

And in console, following error shows.

```
Notified of a data change, but the type was not recognised, so no action taken, type was: undefined
(anonymous function)
d.service.q.logError
o.notifyDataChange
d.service.q.createBoundedWrapper
$scope.toggleFiltering
ib.functionCall
Dc.(anonymous function).compile.d.on.f
$get.l.$eval
$get.l.$apply
(anonymous function)
jQuery.event.dispatch
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has happened me because I was using the latest 'official' `3.0.0-rc.20`. Try to use an unstable version of the ui-grid from [github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/releases). This fixed my problem. Moreover, I'm using version `1.2.28` of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you've injected the **uiGridConstants** in your controller/directive

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants', function ($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) { ... }
```

Comment: This is the most likely cause - the error message you have says that you passed undefined to notify data change, not injecting the constants would cause that

Comment: Thank you, but I've injected the uiGridConstants, so it wasn't a reason.